# asp.net: How to better load Details view fields programmatically instead of copy/paste

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I have the following code for each lookup table. So far I am doing copy/paste for each drop down list control. But I think there is a better way of doing this. I should be able to specify `DataTextField`, `DataValueField`, control names etc. Of course, I will have to manually add configuration related database values on the database side like look up table, and other changes in the stored proc. But at the `.aspx` page or `.cs` page, there has to be a better way then copy/paste..

```
</asp:TemplateField> 
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Your Ethnicity">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEthnicity" runat="server" 
            DataSourceid="ddlDAEthnicity"
            DataTextField="Ethnicity" DataValueField="EthnicityID"
            SelectedValue='<%#Bind("EthnicityID") %>'>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate >
        <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Ethnicity") %>' 
            ID="lblEthnicity">
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

To drive the content in the drop down controls from the database you can bind them using a  number of different DataSource's depending on your architecture.

Here is a simple example (change list box to dropdownlist):

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      DataSourceMode="DataReader"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT LastName FROM Employees">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>

  <asp:ListBox
      id="ListBox1"
      runat="server"
      DataTextField="LastName"
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  </asp:ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Custom control should help you to solve this problem.